# TypeError problem in for statement with range

Tags: python, loops, typeerror

```
## Shell Sort
def ShellSort(list):
    distance = len(list) // 2
    while distance > 0:
        for i in range(distance, len(list)):
            temp = list[i]
            j = i
            while j >= distance and list[j - distance] > temp:
                list[j] = list[j - distance]
                j = j - distance
            list[j] = temp
        distance = distance / 2
    return list
```

Above is the code for 'Shell Sort' I typed after reading the algorithm book.
But if I try to run it, Error occurs on 'for' statement that 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. distance and len(list) are both int type, but I can't find what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`/` means "true division", the result is a `float`. If you want to divide by 2, rounding down to keep `distance` a true `int`, use `//`, which is "floor division". You can save yourself some characters by using `//=`, changing:

```
distance = distance / 2
```

to:

```
distance //= 2
```

which will keep `distance` and `int` (so it remains a compatible argument to `range`).

Side-note: Don't name variables `list` (or any other built-in name); this will bite you when you eventually need to use the `list` constructor in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I think I've missed to check the operator at the end of the loop ...